# How to correctly override Django manage.py's command?

Tags: python, django

I need to override `createsuperuser.py`'s `handle` method in Django `Command` class.

I created myapp\management\commands\createsuperuser.py:

```
import getpass
import sys

import django.contrib.auth.management.commands.createsuperuser as makesuperuser

from django.contrib.auth.management import get_default_username
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from django.core import exceptions
from django.core.management.base import CommandError
from django.utils.encoding import force_str
from django.utils.text import capfirst

class Command(makesuperuser.Command):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # the rest of code is copied from Django source and is almost
        # standart except few changes related to how info of
        # REQUIRED_FIELDS is shown
```

When I do in terminal `./manage.py createsuperuser` I do not see any changes. If I change the name of my file to lets say `mycmd.py` and do `./manage.py mycmd` everything starts to work as I expect.

How to get changes I need using `./manage.py createsuperuser`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your application name on top in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.